# How are Swindler's effects resolved in a multiplayer game?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

I play Swindler in a 3-player game.  Does each player reveal, trash, and gain in turn order, or all reveal, then trash and gain in turn order?

I was thinking that it would matter in the following situation: the player to my left reveals and trashes a Province, so I give him another Province.  This triggers the Fool's Gold in the hand of the next player in turn order.  At this point, would he have already revealed the top card for Swindler, or, since he comes after the player who revealed the Province, is he able to use his Fool's Gold to put a gold on top in time for Swindler to hit it?

Comment: Good question, awful username.

Comment: Thanks...?  I assume you understand my username and still think it's awful, but I'll have you know many think my username is at least "okay."

Comment: I like both the question and your username. :)

Comment: @C0D3BR34K3R, I'm just ribbing you.  Usernames don't really matter anyhow, and what I think of your username doesn't matter either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**  If order matters, then resolve in turn order.

From Intrigue Rulebook:

> Swindler - A player with no cards left in his Deck shuffles first; a
>   player who still has no cards does not trash a card or gain a card. **If
>   the order matters (such as when piles are running low), resolve
>   Swindler in turn order starting with the player to your left.** Gained
>   cards go to discard piles. If a player trashes a 0-cost card such as
>   Copper, you may choose to give him Curse (if there are any left). You
>   can give a player another copy of the same card he trashed. The gained
>   cards have to be ones from the Supply, and you have to pick a card
>   that's left if you can (you cannot pick an empty pile). If there are
>   no cards in the Supply with the same cost as a given player's trashed
>   card, no card is gained by that player. A player who Moats this does
>   not reveal a card from his deck, and so neither trashes a card nor
>   gains a card.

If in doubt or unable to determine `if` turn order matters, I'd suggest using turn order.

Comment: Since the question is of the form 'does X happen or does Y happen', maybe you could be a little more explicit about which of the answers applies in the specific scenario given?  'Yes' seems kind of vague here, and while I think I understand what you mean I'm _still_ not 100% sure...

Comment: This is an interesting Q&A, but a problem comes up when you don't know "if the order matters," until you reveal everyone's top card. Would you still believe that the proper handling of this situation is to have the Fool's Gold player put a Gold on the top of their Deck (to be Swindlec) if the player to their right revealed a Province (1x left on the supply) and they revealed a Duchy (or other VP card). Does the added information change your answer?

Answer (score 7):

**Each player reveals, trashes, and gains in turn order.** The relevant text of Swindler is:

> Each other player trashes the top card of his deck and gains a card with the same cost that you choose.

In Dominion, you do each instruction in order. The convention is that each instruction is one sentence. For Swindler, the instruction is "trash and gain." Having multiple parts of a single instruction is common in Dominion. For instance, the Bureaucrat uses the same construction. In resolving Bureaucrat, the first player must reveal a Victory card and put it on top of their deck, then the second player does both of those things, then the third.

If Swindler wanted everyone to trash, and then everyone to gain, it would have to be written as two separate sentences, and it would be a really messy wording to make sure that the cost of the gained card matches the cost of the card trashed from that player's deck.

Answer (score 4):

The Fool's Gold reveal is optional, but yes, the order is:

Play Swindler.  Resolve any cards that trigger on playing an attack. (Go in order around the table, each player revealing and resolving eligible cards until they are done)

For each player, reveal and trash that card.  Resolve anything that triggers from that trashing (gaining a gold from Tunnel, returning Fortress to hand, discarding Market Square, etc), and resolve anything that triggers from that (like revealing a Watchtower to put that Tunnel Gold on top)  Then choose the card to gain.  Then anything that triggers off of that gain is resolved, (like gaining another card from Border Village).

Then, go onto the next player.

I'm not quite sure who gets to use their Fool's Gold first, if there are not enough Golds.  I think you would start with the player who played the Swindler, and then go around, starting with them.

But in your question; if one has not yet been swindled, trashing the Fool's Gold will result in the gained Gold being swindled.